# Audio live streaming with cracking/distortion on Android devices

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I am working on a Google Action that provides audio live streaming (MP3, 128 kbps), so when testing I have experienced that this live streaming is played with little crackings/distortion after every 2-4 seconds. It looks like that only Android smartphones (Android 10 and 11) are affected with either the Google Assistant app or the built-in Google Assistant that comes with the Pixel phones, it does work well on iOS with the Google Assistant app. The streaming urls play without any problems on Android smartphones when opened with the Chrome app. When investigating this issue it worked with a simple PHP script that kind of proxies the live stream, so I would like to say that the response header is almost unlikely responsible for this behavior.

As my Google Action isn't live yet, I would like to name the Google action of "[Antenne Bayern](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/00000091fb854c08?hl=de_de)" where this behavior is occurring as well.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tested on other devices as well like speakers and/or displays?

Comment: @NickFelker yes, it seems to work on any other device but Android smartphones.

Comment: Are you able to replicate this behavior with other live streams? For instance, try replacing your feed URL with this one https://npr-ice.streamguys1.com/live.mp3?ck=1597372625378

Comment: @Diego Yes I am able to replicate this behavior with other live streams, such as with your provided URL.

Comment: Good. Would it be possible to share a project with me? So I can try it myself. Thanks!